# How do I unhide all objects just on my current active collection?

Tags: object-mode

How do I unhide all objects just on my current active collection? Alt-h unhides stuff even on hidden collections which I find totally bonkers...

Answer (score 2):

In the collections panel, there is an icon that looks like a funnel. This is the Filter drop-down. Click that and activate the eye and the screen icon if either are unseen. Provided both are visible now, shift-click the eye icon twice and the screen icon twice, corresponding to the top level of your collection. This will ensure that everything contained in that selection will be shown.

Comment: I don't want to use the outliner for that because it is so slow. Is there really no way to make alt-h just unhide stuff on  the collection I am working?

Comment: I think this does the same thing as what I described, but you can try selecting the top level collection of what you NEVER want to see, going to the Object Properties context menu tab, and turning off visibility. See if it stays off when you do that or is just same thing. Otherwise idk

Comment: I don't want to turn off anything. I just want to keep my hidden and unhidden objects the way they are on hidden collections. In 2.79 alt-h did not unhide objects on hidden layers so why on earth would I want it to unhide objects on hidden collections when I press alt-h in 2.8?! Sorry for venting but this is incredibly dumb.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is seeing if activating the LOCK icon (again, from the filter dropdown) would keep visibility settings in place while you hide/unhide objects in another collection. If you try it, don't forget to shift-click when you turn on the lock or it might not lock everything. I have not tested this at all. Yeah, it sounds impractical, sorry

Comment: I think a script tied to the alt-h keyboard shortcut should work. I have absolutely no idea how to do it though. Basically a script that unhides all the objects on the active collection and nowhere else like it should be.